# Rust struct into PyObject in rust-cpython

Tags: python, rust, cpython, python-cffi

I am using rust-cpython to write functions in Rust that is callable in Python.

I have an existing struct that is used as an output. How to I make this into a PyObject that rust-cpython can understand?

My struct looks like this:

```
struct Block {
    start: i32,
    stop: i32,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My compilation error said I needed to implement the ToPyObject trait on my struct.
To represent my struct in one of the PyObject types, I decided to use a PyDict.

I looked at how rust-cpython does it for [HashMap](https://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/src/cpython/objects/dict.rs.html#129-143) and I just copied it over.

```
impl ToPyObject for Block {
    type ObjectType = PyDict;

    fn to_py_object(&self, py: Python) -> PyDict {
        let dict = PyDict::new(py);
        dict.set_item(py, "start", self.start).unwrap();
        dict.set_item(py, "stop", self.stop).unwrap();

        dict
    }
}
```

This is kind of a hack but it allows me to pass data with named fields as keys.